# Sailfish OS Obfuscator

Tags: qtcreator

Всем привет, ведется разработка под Sailfish OS. Нужна обфускация кода. Ничего путного найти не могу, можете что нибудь посоветовать?

Comment: а что c++ компилятор недостаточно обфусцирует?

Comment: с++ код используется ещё в qml страницах, поэтому нельзя обфусцировать его отдельно

Comment: как это вы себе представляете? c++ код внутри QML что-ли?

Comment: Есть c++ и отдельно qml, функции из cpp файлов используются в qml, поэтому отдельно обфусцировать  его нельзя

Comment: Короче в случае если главная программа на C++, то советуют просто шифровать qml и расшифровывать при выполнении. Если же главная программа на QML, то вам поможет наверное qml compiler, но он только в коммерческой версии. Не думаю, что кто-то обфускатор для QML написал.